# How to reference the arguments defined in a "newcommand"?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, coordinates

**What I am doing:**
I want to draw a picture (as shown below) to illustrate the contraction of some intervals to nodes in a line.
[image: Intervals]

First, I define a `newcommand` for interval (i.e., \op) with three arguments: start point, end point, and the name. Then, a line (or a chain) is drawn. At last, the interval and its corresponding node in the line are connected.
The whole code is: (*Note:* you can also read and modify the shared code at [SharedLatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/52c24becef7483b768001d5b) before any answer is accepted.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, chains}

\title{Reference Arguments in Newcommand}
\author{hengxin}
\date{31 December 2013}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]

% new command: inverval
\newcommand{\op}[3] % #1: start point; #2: end point; #3: interval name
{
  \coordinate (start) at #1;    % start point
  \coordinate (end) at #2;  % end point
  \coordinate (mid) at ($0.5*#1 + 0.5*#2 + (0,0.8cm)$);

  \draw[ultra thick, blue, |-|] (start) -- (end); % draw the interval
  \node (#3) [font = \huge] at (mid) {#3};  % attach the operation name
}

% define three intervals
\op{(0,2)}{(2,2)}{$a$};
\op{(4,3)}{(6,3)}{$b$};
\op{(7,2)}{(10,2)}{$c$};

% contract them into single nodes in a line (or a chain)
\begin{scope}[font = \huge, start chain = schedule, node distance = 3.0cm, every     join/.style = {very thick, ->, red}]
  \foreach \opi in {a, b, c}
    \node (\opi) [circle, draw, on chain, join, label = {[] below : $\opi$}] {};
\end{scope}

% connect interval and its corresponding node in the line
\begin{scope}[cedge/.style = {->, dashed, draw, thick}]
  \draw [cedge] (0,2) to (a);
  \draw [cedge] (2,2) to (a);

  \draw [cedge] (4,3) to (b);
  \draw [cedge] (6,3) to (b);

  \draw [cedge] (7,2) to (c);
  \draw [cedge] (10,2) to (c);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**What I want to do:**
As you can see, in the last step (connecting interval and its corresponding node in the line) I have hard-coded the coordinates of the start points and end points of each interval like `\draw [cedge] (0,2) to (a); \draw [cedge] (2,2) to (a);`. It is surely tedious and error-prone. Therefore,

> Is there some elegant way for me to reference the two points (as arguments of `newcommand`) of each interval without hard-code?

Comment: Are you okay with the new version of your code on SharedLatex?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Not now... It must be under revisions by some people who are trying to help. Maybe it is not a good idea to release its write permission. However, you can copy the code in the post and modify it locally. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @PaulGaborit NOW, I am happy with new version. Is it your answer? Sorry for the misunderstanding in my last comment. However, could you please post it as an answer and make some brief explanations? And then I will accept it if everything goes well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `\op` command, you can name each limit of your interval (using `#3` as part of the name).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % new command: inverval
  \newcommand{\op}[3]{ % #1: start point; #2: end point; #3: operation name
    \coordinate (start #3) at #1;   % start point
    \coordinate (end #3) at #2; % end point

    \draw[ultra thick, blue, |-|] (start #3) -- (end #3) % draw the interval
    node[pos=.5,above=8mm,font=\huge, text=black] {$#3$}; % attach the operation name
  }
  % define three intervals
  \op{(0,2)}{(2,2)}{a};
  \op{(4,3)}{(6,3)}{b};
  \op{(7,2)}{(10,2)}{c};
  % contract them into single nodes in a line (or a chain)
  \begin{scope}[font=\huge, start chain=schedule, node distance=3.0cm,
    every join/.style={very thick, ->, red}]
    \foreach \opi in {a, b, c} {
      \node [circle,draw,on chain,join,label={[]below:$\opi$}] (\opi) {};
    }
  \end{scope}
  % connect interval and its corresponding node in the line
  \begin{scope}[cedge/.style = {->, dashed, draw, thick}]
    \foreach \interval in {a,b,c}{
      \draw [cedge] (start \interval) to (\interval);
      \draw [cedge] (end \interval) to (\interval);
    }
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works well. Thx. However, still one question about the code `\draw [cedge] (start \interval) to (\interval);`: does the second `\interval` refer to each *node* in the line? If so, why can we still use `start \interval` to refer to the `start` argument of an *interval*? Why are `a,b,c` not overwritten by the previous `foreach` statement (i.e., `\foreach \opi in {a, b, c}`)?

Comment: @hengxin `(start \interval)` and `(end \interval)` are the names of coordinates of extremities of an (blue) interval (a, b or c) and `(\interval)` is a node (a, b or c) on the (red) chain of contracted intervals.